# Transfering files in a client-server socket connection properly

Tags: c, sockets, file-upload

I have written the following code for sending file from a client:

```
FILE *fp = fopen("video.mp4","rb");
        if(fp==NULL)
        {
            printf("File opern error");
            return 1;   
        } 

int bytesToWrite=84440670;
int bytesWritten=0; 
while(bytesWritten<bytesToWrite)
    {
        int m=minimum(256,bytesToWrite-bytesWritten);
        /* First read file in chunks of 256 bytes or the remaining bytes*/
        unsigned char *buff=malloc(sizeof(char)*m);
        bzero(buff, m);
        int nread = fread(buff,1,m,fp);
        printf("Bytes read %d \n", nread);  
        bytesWritten+=m;   

        /* If read was success, send data. */
        if(nread > 0)
        {
            printf("Sending \n");
            write(sockfd, buff, nread);
        }

        /*
         * There is something tricky going on with read .. 
         * Either there was error, or we reached end of file.
         */
        if (nread < 256)
        {
            if (feof(fp))
                printf("End of file\n");
            if (ferror(fp))
                printf("Error reading\n");
            break;
        }


    }
```

and the following code for receiving by the server :

```
FILE *fp;
        fp = fopen("receive.mp4", "wb"); 
        if(NULL == fp)
        {
            printf("Error opening file");
            return 1;
        }
        int bytesToRead=84440670;
        /* Receive data in chunks of 256 or remaining bytes */
        int totalbytesread=0;
        while(totalbytesread < bytesToRead)
        {
            int m = minimum(256,bytesToRead-totalbytesread);
            char *recvBuff=malloc(sizeof(char)*m);
            bzero(recvBuff,m);
            bytesReceived = read(newsocfd, recvBuff,m );
            printf("Bytes received %d\n",bytesReceived);
            totalbytesread += bytesReceived;   
            fwrite(recvBuff, 1,bytesReceived,fp);
        }

        if(bytesReceived < 0)
        {
            printf("\n Read Error \n");
        }
```

The sending is working correctly for .txt files ,some data is being lost in sending other formats(for e.g some ending seconds of .mp4 files is not being sent).
I am new to socket programming. Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: I don't know the reason, but there is a memory leaks on each iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a `fclose(fp);` in the server after you have finished receiving. You can also use `fflush(fp);` to just flush the contents.

Besides, there are several memory leaks and improper error handling.